# How to remove external js in jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation, methods

> I am creating one generic  external js file for validation of forms 
>   that works on every page in my project. In one of my page i have 2
>   conditions on form.For that i want to remove my js file that loads on
>   every time when page refresh. I used this code but it wont work for
>   me.

```
$('script[src="include/javascript/gen_validatorv4.js"]').remove();
```

Or if its not possible then can i stop my function from gen_validatorv4.js on certain page.

```
function Validator(frmname)
{
    this.validate_on_killfocus = false;
    this.formobj = document.forms[frmname];
    if (!this.formobj)
    {
        alert("Error: couldnot get Form object " + frmname);
        return;
    }
    if (this.formobj.onsubmit)
    {
        this.formobj.old_onsubmit = this.formobj.onsubmit;
        this.formobj.onsubmit = null;
    }
    else
    {
        this.formobj.old_onsubmit = null;
    }

}
```

Can i stop my function `validator` in some pages from loading.
In one of my page i have one form where i am having one dropdown list.

```
<select id="org_id">
    <option value="1">ABC</option>
    <option value="2">DEF</option>
    <option value="3">XYZ</option>
</select>
```

If user will select ABC from dropdown then only my external js should not work. If user will select any other option then `Validator` function should work.

```
   if(value == '1')
            {

                //window.enableValidator = false;
                $('script[src="include/javascript/gen_validatorv4.js"]').remove();

            }
        else if(value != '1')
            {               

                var frmvalidator = new Validator("add_employee_frm");
                frmvalidator.addValidation("employee_number","req","Please Enter Employee Number");
                frmvalidator.addValidation("employee_name","req","Please Enter Employee Name");
                frmvalidator.addValidation("employee_name","alphabetic_space","Please Enter Valid Employee Name")

            }
```

This is what i done yet. Now i think you can give me better soution.
`include/javascript/gen_validatorv4.js"]` this is my external script with function Validator inside it. its onload function. So basically for my situation i have to remove this script or unbind it in my if condition so that i wont get any validation errors in if condition.

Comment: Set a boolean flag on a global variable and check it in your Validator function if it should validate or not?

Comment: @Adriani6 can you provide me code for this or links

Comment: See my answer below as it's too much to post as a comment.

Comment: If the validator function has global scope then you can just override it by adding another validator function that has the same signature but does nothing.  That would mean you could leave all the existing code as is and re-enable validation later by just removing the overriding function.

Comment: @Archer What if you'll want to re-enable it on the next view (assuming it's partial views)? You'll need to reload the functions code?

Comment: @Adriani6 Why are you assuming it's partial views??  There's nothing here to even suggest any type of MVC framework.

Comment: Just for the sake of argument. It's not specified what is used by OP so I'm providing a generic solution while yours is correct too you won't be able to re-enable the function on condition. I'm not trying to cause a stir, just more of a knowledge exchange in case I missed something :) Doesn't have to be MVC for it to have partial views or pages loaded dynamically.

Comment: @Adriani6 No need to confuse the issue by introducing what if's.  What if the OP cannot modify `gen_validatorv4.js`?  Then your proposed solution is 100% incorrect.  If you've got a question then ask the OP.  My comment was to them, so let them weigh up the best course of action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with what you're trying to do is that even though you remove the script element from the page, the javascript will still execute as it already loaded.. you can add more scripts (load them dynamically) but you'll never fully remove it unfortunately.

Set a boolean flag on a global variable and check it in your Validator function if it should validate or not.

When you load your page where you don't want to enable the validator; do something like this:

```
window.enableValidator = false;
```

This line of code assigns boolean (false) to the window object.

Your validator script would change to accommodate a check before running the validation...

```
if(window.enableValidator){ 
   // wrap your code in here 
}
```

Comment: i made changes in my question please go through with it

Comment: Again as I said, my solution for your problem stands correct as a way of achieving the desired result.

Comment: im adding your code in my view fie on top. and in my if condition where i dont want to dispay validations i am adding your if condtion. but its not working

Comment: Show your code; put it in jsfiddle don't put it in the comments.